# Split each string in list and store in multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

I have a list that looks like this: `['1 0 0','2 0.5 0.25','3 1 0.5','4 1.5 0.75']`

I want to end up with these three arrays: `[1,2,3,4]` and `[0,0.5,1,1.5]` and `[0,0.25,0.5,0.75]`

i.e. I want the first value of each list item and store it in an array, and do the same with the second and third values.

I tried this

```
for i in coordinates[:]:
    number,x,y=i.split(' ')
```

also tried using `number[]` and `number.append`
but none of these seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating three new list, and going through a input:

```
input = ['1 0 0','2 0.5 0.25','3 1 0.5','4 1.5 0.75']
x_list = []
y_list = []
z_list = []

for i in input:
    x, y, z = i.split(' ')
    x_list.append(x)
    y_list.append(y)
    z_list.append(z)
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done as follows:

```
list(zip(*(list(map(float, s.split())) for s in coordinates)))
```

First we loop through all strings in the list and split them

```
[s.split() for s in coordinates]
```

Then we `map` the `float` function over all the individual strings to convert them to floats:

```
[list(map(float, s.split())) for s in coordinates]
```

Then we use `zip` to get them the way you want them.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @ikkuh's but with "configurable" types:

```
data = ['1 0 0','2 0.5 0.25','3 1 0.5','4 1.5 0.75']
tp = [int, float, float] 

parsed = ((t(j) for t, j in zip(tp, record.split())) for record in data)
idx, x, y = (list(i) for i in zip(*parsed))
idx
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
x
# [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
y
# [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]
```

Comment: Python 2 version: `map(map, tp, zip(*map(str.split, data)))`. Not sure I ever mapped `map` before :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Gosh, that does qualify as unreadable. Transposing first looks like a good idea btw.

Comment: Well, I think it's quite readable. But yeah, one reason I didn't post it as answer is that I'm not in the mood for explaining it :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann It's the nested `map`s where I - or rather my spinning head - draw the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach without for loop , using lambda :

```
a=['1 0 0','2 0.5 0.25','3 1 0.5','4 1.5 0.75']

print(list(zip(*list((map(lambda y:y.split(),a))))))
```

output:

```
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('0', '0.5', '1', '1.5'), ('0', '0.25', '0.5', '0.75')]
```